# Why is my JavaFX label's text garbled, and how can I fix it to show my requested string?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

this is my code:

```
package HelloWorld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class helloworld extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Label l = new Label();
        l.setText("Hello World");
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1000, 1000);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println(l.textProperty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The result is the window opening with the correct title, but the text is just utter gibberish and completely not understandable, as seen below:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result? (Or are you referring to the result of the `System.out.println(...)` statement?)

Comment: Here: https://imgur.com/B5WOd6C
the system.out.println works fine actually and shows that the label's text is indeed "Hello World" @James_D

Comment: That's weird. It looks like a character encoding issue?

Comment: Thanks for editing. Do you have an idea as to how to fix this?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: Well thanks anyway

Comment: I would see this behavior on old versions (e.g. 11) of JavaFX on OS X.  Updating to a later JavaFX version (e.g. 19+) fixed it.